# How to get the value from an array and assign to array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the values from an array and assign to an array of objects as a new property.
The array of objects:

```
const employees = [
  {
    firstName: "Ana",
    lastName: "Rosy"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Zion",
    lastName: "Albert"
  },
  {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
  }
];
```

An array

```
const ages = [30, 60, 45]
```

Desired result

```
const employees = [
  {
    firstName: "Ana",
    lastName: "Rosy",
    age:30
  },
  {
    firstName: "Zion",
    lastName: "Albert",
    age:60
  },
  {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age:45
  }
];
```

I tried something like this

```
const employeesWithAge = (ages) => {
  return employees.map((row) => {
    return {
      ...row,
      age: ages
    };
  });
};
const result = employeesWithAge(ages);
console.log("result", result);
```

But it adds the entire array of `ages` to the `employees` array of objects.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this. Use the [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) on the current element to copy the properties into a new object, then add the `age` property based on the `ages` array, using `.map()` callback's second parameter (the current index).

```js
employees.map((employee, i) => ({...employee, age: ages[i]}));
```

Live example:

```js
const employees = [{
    firstName: "Ana",
    lastName: "Rosy"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Zion",
    lastName: "Albert"
  },
  {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
  }
];

const ages = [30, 60, 45];

const result = employees.map((employee, i) => ({ ...employee, age: ages[i] }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple **for** loop should solve your problem.

```
for (let i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
  employees[i]["age"] = ages[i];
}
```

This loop iterates through the length of your list of employee objects and adds a new "age" attribute to each object with the corresponding age in your ages array.

All together I imagine your code looking something like this.

```
const employees = [
  {
    firstName: "Ana",
    lastName: "Rosy"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Zion",
    lastName: "Albert"
  },
  {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
  }
];

const ages = [30, 60, 45];

for (let i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
  employees[i]["age"] = ages[i];
}

console.log(employees);
```